# How to appending an element to column array in Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to  appending an element to column array in Panda Dataframe 
I have a dataframe and I added a column including empty array

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], "b": [3, 4, 6]})

df1["c"] = [[]] * df1.shape[0]
```

Output

```
    a   b   c
0   0   3   []
1   1   4   []
2   2   6   []
```

Now I want to append an element to the array in column 'c' 
This is what i have tried:

```
df1["c"][2].append(1)

Output:
    a   b    c
0   0   3   [1]
1   1   4   [1]
2   2   6   [1]
```

I was expecting:

```
    a   b    c
0   0   3   []
1   1   4   []
2   2   6   [1]
```

Comment: `df1["c"] = [list() for _ in range(df1.shape[0])]`

Comment: @G.Anderson ^ Worked for me. Thank you so much.